# Apache2: Rewrite url to different port on localhost

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

There is a service on my local computer available on `127.0.0.1:8080`, but I would prefer to use it rather like `127.0.0.1/qwerty/`

I tried to add in */etc/apache2/sites-available/default*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (qwerty/.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1
```

Before that I symlinked rewrite.load in mods-enabled and restarted apache2 server.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

---

**Edit:**
To be more specific - This  service is calibre-server and its output is on port `8080`, while on port `80` works apache2. Then I'd like to do the same with my flask (python micro framework) project (it works on port `5000`).

---

**Edit 2:**
I used reversed proxy trick from [link](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/server.html), typing `calibre-server --url-prefix /calibre` in command line and it works (<s>without proxying anything</s> i needed to set proxy in  */etc/apache2/sites-available/default*).

What does not work is this flask thing.

I will write down everything I did, because I'm not sure I understood correctly.
@Ωmega : I do start flask project by typing `python demo.py` in demo directory.
I created `.htaccess` file in this directory and put there the line you've suggested and it didn't work, so I changed all file content to:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1/flask/ [R=301,L]
```

but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In settings for ***directory*** that serves `http://127.0.0.1:8080` do the following redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1/qwerty/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: do you mean by directory settings the `.htaccess` file in the directory?

Comment: @dmeu :: Create an admin-specific `.htaccess` file in the directory that serves `http://127.0.0.1:8080`